# postgresql: deleting from a view

Tags: postgresql, trigger, view, postgresql-9.4

In Postgresql 9.4, we're doing a view as a UNION of to tables A and B, and we'd like to have a single DELETED N ROWS message when we 'delete' the records in the underlying tables (via a a trigger on the view).

Here's more detailed info. Our views look like,

```
A
--
id, name
1, afoo
2, abar

B
--
id, name
3, bfoo
4, bbar
```

So our view C looks like

```
C
--
1, afoo
2, abar
3, bfoo
4, bbar
```

We did a `CREATE TRIGGER delete_trigger INSTEAD OF DELETE C FOR EACH ROW DO delete_trigger()`, which delete the rows by id which basically its like

```
-- our function trigger():
$$
delete from A where id=old.id;
GET DIAGNOSTICS deletedA = ROW_COUNT;

delete from B where id=old.id;
GET DIAGNOSTICS deletedB = ROW_COUNT;

raise notice 'deleted % records from A, % records from B', deletedA , deletedB;

$$
```

If we issue a command like `delete * from C;`, our ideal goal would be to have a single message that said

```
deleted 2 records from A, 2 records from B
```

But instead we have - because we don't know better -,

```
deleted 1 records from A, 0 records from B 
deleted 1 records from A, 0 records from B 
deleted 0 records from A, 1 records from B 
deleted 0 records from A, 0 records from B
```

Is it possible to get a single sum of deleted records?

We're also worried about the performance of this.

Any and all help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The triggered event is invoked for each row.

The syntax is

`CREATE TRIGGER c_view_delete_trg INSTEAD OF DELETE
   ON c_view
   FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE c_view_delete();`

This means that the function is invoked once for each row that is being deleted. this is why it prints each time one row.

Comment: I'd say that his question is more in the sense of how do we do it in one batch, instead of row by row. If that is possible.

Comment: Don't think that is possible. Instead of statements are row-level statements. Take a look here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: Why wouldn't `FOR EACH STATEMENT` (which is the default) give the expected result?